# PowerApps - canvas How to scroll two forms without splitting the screen space

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have 'general_form' that is always on a page and 'secondary_form' that is dependent on a checkbox in 'general_form'. To make 'secondary_form' visible based on the check isn't a problem, what I can't figure out is how to make them scrollable without making a separate screen for them.

As a result I have this abomination...[image]

Any suggestions?

I tried putting them in a gallery but I can't. Making a separate scrollable screen for them would be a pain.